# How to bind a list of list to a ListView control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, binding

I have The following structure

`QPage` class Object contains a `List<List<QLine>>`
`QLine` object contains `List<Qword>`

every list of words constructs a line and every list of lines consists a group(paragraph) and every list of paragraphs consists a page.

I want to bind the page to structure like this in XAML

```
<ListView>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock>                 
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</ListView>
```

where each item of the ListView is a paragraph(`List<QLine>`) and each vertical stack panel holds an item of the `List<QLine>` and each item of the horizontal stack panel holds an item of the `List<Qword>` and the texblock is bound to `Qword.text` property. I have no idea how to do such binding from the XAML code.

Comment: +1 for this as it's quite interesting. Just to get the basics going though, you should provide an ID of some sort to the ListView so that in the code behind you can do `listView.Source = ....;` Then in the XAML, in the TextBlock, you can do `Text = {Binding TheObjectName}` where TheObjectName can be QWord.

Lastly, I would not have it so that the structure is unambiguous, i.e. `List<List<QLine>>>` I would make it so that it's all within an object structure i.e. Classes containing those objects which will help with the binding when it comes to providing a Name for the property in XAML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully I did not miss some list but this should work. Basically it's a `ListBox` that hosts `List<List<QLine>>` (called it `QPageList`). Then you have `ItemsControl` that hosts each `List<QLine>` in vertical panel and finally there is another `ItemsControl` that hosts `List<Qword>` from `QLine` (called it `QwordList`) where each `QWord` is displayed as `TextBlock` on horizontal `StackPanel`

```
<!-- ItemsSource: List<List<QLine>>, Item: List<QLine> -->
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding QPageList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- ItemsSource: List<QLine>, Item: QLine -->
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- ItemsSource: QLine.List<QWord>, Item: QWord --> 
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding QwordList}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <!-- Item: QWord -->
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: That's pretty much it. Only you forgot to bind to QLine :)

Comment: Did I? Quite possible with all this lists but I've just added comments with types and I think it should work

Comment: I think you actually didn't because you can't bind to line, there's no line object, only list<list<line>> and list<word>.. your solution worked as it is. so thank you very much :)

Comment: I stand corrected :). Wouldn't be the first time today too. Something about mondays I dunno.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `ListView.ItemTemplate`. Basically, you need to provide your list with a way to understand the nested data structure of your rows.

Here is a good tutorial to get you started on [ItemTemplates](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/).

Once your list has an item template then you just bind the ListView directly to your data source and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefuly this will prove helpful. [Taken from here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/harryh/archive/2010/06/12/nested-collections-databinding-in-xaml-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx)

```
Authors (list)
 - - Name
 - - Books (list)
     | -  - Title
     | -  - Contents
```

Sample code :

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate1">
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate2">
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource AuthorDataSource}}">
    <ListBox x:Name="AuthorList" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemTemplate1}" ItemsSource="{Binding Authors }" >
    <ListBox x:Name="BookList"  DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=AuthorList}" ItemsSource="{Binding Books }" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemTemplate2}" />
    <TextBlock  x:Name="BookContent"   DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=BookList}"  Text="{Binding Contents }" />
  </Grid>
```

Comment: Using Grids to do this feels somewhat strange. Also you loose virtualization on your lists. This will slaughter your apps performance on a large enough list. I imagine anything with 1000 items will make it unusable.

Comment: @Alex but the grid is a layout panel that arranges its child controls in a tabular structure of rows and columns, I fail to see how this could add a large performance overhead.

Comment: It will attempt to render ALL child controls. ListView and some other controls use virtualization to reuse visible components to render bound data on scrolling. Basically you are scrolling the data rather than visible elements.

Comment: Isn't virtualisation ruled by the size of the viewport?, i.e. set a size to the child controls 'ItemsControl' or the ListBoxes and you achieve virtualisation in the grid. Besides which I wouldn't like to make any assumptions on the size of the lists and what would be best, i.e. holding a large list in memory might not be the best thing.

Comment: Nope. Otherwise there would be no need to VirtualizingStackPanel :)

Comment: Doesn't this say otherwise? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780657.aspx ListBox being one of the controls that has the base class of ItemsControl which itself supports virtualisation.

Comment: Eh? "Using virtualization with a list or grid" is the page title, and "Note  ItemsControl is the base class for several common collection controls, including ListView, GridView, FlipView, ListBox, and ComboBox controls. These examples use the ListView and GridView controls, but the info applies generally to ItemsControls."

Comment: This is is dragging on :) Dude, GridView supports virtualization. Grid doesn't! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx VS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx. You are saying everything correct but your example uses Grid rather than GridView. Big difference.

Answer (score 0):

Forward to what Alex is saying, it'd be a good idea to `Encapsulate` (If that's the correct word here) the object within classes, i.e.:

```
public class Page
{
    public List<Paragraph> Paragraphs { get; set; }
}

public class Paragraph
{
    public List<QWord> Sentences { get; set; }
}

public class Sentence
{
    public List<QWord> Words { get; set; }
}
```

That'd help when you bind data in your XAML, i.e. if you look at the tutorial which Alex provided:

```
<TextBlock Text="Name: " />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" FontWeight="Bold" />
<TextBlock Text=" (" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Mail}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
<TextBlock Text=")" />
```

Hope that helps you.